# Can we separate the Impact people reached by category?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, people-reached

Is it good to separate the `Impact people reached` by **category**(*questions and answers*) so we could identify on which category you have more impact?

Like this:

[image: proposal]

Comment: Why would you want that? (Not that I am against, but I had like to know how this helps)

Comment: to identify on which category you helped more.. also it would be better if the impact is categorized.

Comment: What does it matter?

Comment: well, since they added that feature, why not make it to be categorized to identify which category you have more impact. but it's just my own point of view :).. if it doesn't make sense, then just remain it not to categorize :)

Comment: I could see wanting this by tag, but I don't see the utility in Q vs. A.